# Find if we can get palindrome

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a string S.We need to tell if we can make it to palindrome by removing exactly one letter from it or not.
I have a O(N^2) approach by modifying Edit Distance method.Is their any better way ?

My Approach :

```
int ModifiedEditDistance(const string& a, const string& b, int k) {
    int i, j, n = a.size();
    int dp[MAX][MAX];
    memset(dp, 0x3f, sizeof dp);    
    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        dp[i][0] = dp[0][i] = i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int from = max(1, i-k), to = min(i+k, n);
        for (j = from; j <= to; j++) {
            if (a[i-1] == b[j-1])           // same character
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-1];    
            // note that we don't allow letter substitutions

            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], 1 + dp[i][j-1]); // delete character j
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j], 1 + dp[i-1][j]); // insert character i
        }
    }
    return dp[n][n];
}
```

How to improve space complexity as max size of string can go upto 10^5.

Please help.

Example : Let String be abc then answer is "NO" and if string is "abbcbba then answer is "YES"

Comment: `abbcbba` is a palindrome already, without removing anything.

Comment: @JohnZwinck But we need to remove EXACTLY one character .And then tell the answer.So removing "c" will still make it palindrome.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think he means that you can remove the `'c'` and it's still a palindrome.

Comment: Is this a problem from an online programming judge? Which?

Comment: Is a solution with polynomial hash fine(it has some probability of a collision, but with 2 or more hashes it is pretty low)?

Comment: @SlySherZ How?Please explain

Comment: Think. How would you solve the problem on paper? You'd probably run a finger from each end of the word towards the middle, checking for differences.

Comment: This is too broad; should be on code review.

Comment: @Qix it's not too broad at all. It's quite specific.

Comment: Please remember to choose an answer as the accepted one, if you found them useful (gets you some rep points too).

Comment: @chiastic-security `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.` I'll say it again; this question belongs on CodeReview.

Answer (score 9):

The key observation is that if the first and last characters are the same then you needn't remove either of them; which is to say that `xSTRINGx` can be turned into a palindrome by removing a single letter if and only if `STRING` can (as long as `STRING` is at least one character long).

You want to define a method (excuse the Java syntax--I'm not a C++ coder):

```
boolean canMakePalindrome(String s, int startIndex, int endIndex, int toRemove);
```

which determines whether the part of the string from `startIndex` to `endIndex-1` can be made into a palindrome by removing `toRemove` characters.

When you consider `canMakePalindrome(s, i, j, r)`, then you can define it in terms of smaller problems like this:

1. If `j-i` is 1 then return true; if it's 0 then return true if and only if `r` is 0. The point here is that a 1-character string is a palindrome regardless of whether you remove a character; a 0-length string is a palindrome, but can't be made into one by removing a character (because there aren't any to remove).
2. If `s[i]` and `s[j-1]` are the same, then it's the same answer as `canMakePalindrome(s, i+1, j-1, r)`.
3. If they're different, then either `s[i]` or `s[j-1]` needs removing. If `toRemove` is zero, then return false, because you haven't got any characters left to remove. If `toRemove` is 1, then return true if either `canMakePalindrome(s, i+1, j, 0)` or `canMakePalindrome(s, i, j-1, 0)`. This is because you're now testing whether it's already a palindrome if you remove one of those two characters.

Now this can be coded up pretty easily, I think.

If you wanted to allow for removal of more than one character, you'd use the same idea, but using dynamic programming. With only one character to remove, dynamic programming will reduce the constant factor, but won't reduce the asymptotic time complexity (linear in the length of the string).

Comment: What is the time complexity of this solution?

Comment: @chiastic-security Can you please provide some pseudocode ?

Comment: @user2040251 It's linear, I think (because you can only remove one character).

Comment: @chiastic-security A pseudocode will make it more clear i guess

Comment: @j_random_hacker did you mean to post that on a different answer?

Comment: @androidmaniac it O(1) on the heap, O(n) run time. It should be noted that if you implement it verbatim with recursion, it'll be O(n) on the *stack* as well, most likely leading to a stack overflow. However, describing algorithms as a recursion is a very common thing to do, you just need to be smart enough to write it as a for loop instead of calls. The above is equivalent to my answer or JohnWincks answer.

Comment: @chiastic-security: I guess John Zwinck must have deleted his comment, since I don't see it now.  (I recall that his name auto-completed when I typed "@Joh", so I don't *think* I was hallucinating... ;) )  I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: Compilers are actually effective in doing tail recursion optimization, but I guess that programmers are not that good in ensuring that their function is tail-recursive... but a tail recursive function can be both simple to understand and efficient.

Comment: this is a problem of ongoing contest and must be closed http://www.codechef.com/NOV14/problems/PRPALN

Comment: @aksam I understand what you're saying, but I don't see anything in the Stack Overflow rules that require this to be closed, and codechef doesn't have the authority to kill off questions here. The internet is a big place, and you're not going to keep such things under wraps whatever you do.

Answer (score 4):

Psudocode (Something like this I havn't tested it at all).

It is based on detecting the conditions that you CAN remove a character, ie

1. There is exactly 1 wrong character
2. It is a palendrome (0 mismatch)

O(n) in time, O(1) in space.

```
 bool foo(const std::string& s)
 {
   int i = 0;
   int j = s.size()-1;
   int mismatch_count = 0;
   while (i < j)
   {
       if (s[i]==s[j])
       {
          i++; j--;
       }
       else
       {
          mismatch_count++;
          if (mismatch_count > 1) break;
          //override first preference if cannot find match for next character
          if (s[i+1] == s[j] && ((i+2 >= j-1)||s[i+2]==s[j-1]))
          {
             i++;
          }
          else if (s[j-1]==s[i])
          {
             j--;
          }
          else
          {
             mismatch_count++; break;
          }
       }
    }  
    //can only be a palendrome if you remove a character if there is exactly one mismatch
    //or if a palendrome
    return (mismatch_count == 1) || (mismatch_count == 0);
 }
```

Comment: Your code seems to be wrong as it provide 0 for aaa and abba

Comment: returns 1 for me? Both of those are planedromes so mismatch_count==0

Comment: But we can still remove a single character and they will still be palindromes.So answer should be 1 and not 0

Comment: @androidmaniac `return (mismatch_count == 1) || (mismatch_count == 0);` checks for that?

Comment: @androidmaniac still getting that error? I'm confused at how you could be :-/

Comment: @ MadScienceDreams The strings are big to be pasted here.But when i run your solution vs JohnZwinck solution then both have different answers.And his solution were right .

Comment: How can anyone help you when you state the strings are too big to be pasted here?  What is this fermat's last theorem whose proof you have but its too long to fit the paper?

Comment: @JonH finding the bug is left as an exercise for the reader :-P

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (slightly incomplete) solution which takes O(n) time and O(1) space.

```
// returns index to remove to make a palindrome; string::npos if not possible
size_t willYouBeMyPal(const string& str)
{
  size_t toRemove = string::npos;
  size_t len = str.length();

  for (size_t c1 = 0, c2 = len - 1; c1 < c2; ++c1, --c2) {
    if (str[c1] != str[c2]) {
      if (toRemove != string::npos) {
        return string::npos;
      }

      bool canRemove1 = str[c1 + 1] == str[c2];
      bool canRemove2 = str[c1] == str[c2 - 1];
      if (canRemove1 && canRemove2) {
        abort(); // TODO: handle the case where both conditions are true
      } else if (canRemove1) {
        toRemove = c1++;
      } else if (canRemove2) {
        toRemove = c2--;
      } else {
        return string::npos;
      }
    }
  }

  // if str is a palindrome already, remove the middle char and it still is
  if (toRemove == string::npos) {
    toRemove = len / 2;
  }

  return toRemove;
}
```

Left as an exercise is what to do if you get this:

```
abxyxcxyba
```

The correct solution is:

```
ab_yxcxyba
```

But you might be led down a bad path:

```
abxyxcx_ba
```

So when you find the "next" character on both sides is a possible solution, you need to evaluate both possibilities.

Comment: @androidmaniac: you're right, I fixed it by simplifying the condition at the end where we fix up cases which were already palindromes.

Comment: it give npos for abdbca

Comment: @androidmaniac: correct again, I had just found that bug myself and fixed it simultaneous with you finding it.  :)  I had `c2++` where I needed `c2--`.  It now gives `4` for `abdbca` which makes `abdba`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck good catch on the multiple paths. I hope you don't mind, I stole it for my answer :-P

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a sample with O(n) complexity that works for the tests I threw at it. Not many though :D
The idea behind it is to ignore the first and last letters if they are the same, deleting one of them if they are not, and reasoning what happens when the string is small enough. The same result could be archived with a loop instead of the recursion, which would save some space (making it O(1)), but it's harder to understand and more error prone IMO.

```
bool palindrome_by_1(const string& word, int start, int end, bool removed = false)  // Start includes, end excludes
{
    if (end - start == 2){
        if (!removed)
            return true;

        return word[start] == word[end - 1];
    }

    if (end - start == 1)
        return true;


    if (word[start] == word[end - 1])
        return palindrome_by_1(word, start + 1, end - 1, removed);

    // After this point we need to remove a letter
    if (removed) 
        return false;

    // When two letters don't match, try to eliminate one of them
    return palindrome_by_1(word, start + 1, end, true) || palindrome_by_1(word, start, end - 1, true);

}
```

Comment: @chiastic-security wrote an answer that uses the same concept I did. It wasn't my intention xD

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a single string is palindrome is O(n). You can implement a similar algorithm than moves two pointers, one from the start and another from the end. Move each pointer as long as the chars are the same, and on the first mismatch try to match which char you can skip, and keep moving both pointers as long as the rest chars are the same. Keep track of the first mismatch. This is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

I hope my algorithm will pass without providing code.

If a word a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>....a<sub>n</sub> can be made a palindrome by removing a<sub>k</sub>, we can search for k as following:

If a<sub>1</sub> != a<sub>n</sub>, then the only possible k would be 1 or n. Just check if a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>....a<sub>n-1</sub> or a<sub>2</sub>a<sub>3</sub>....a<sub>n</sub> is a palindrome.

If a<sub>1</sub> == a<sub>n</sub>, next step is solving the same problem for a<sub>2</sub>....a<sub>n-1</sub>.  So we have a recursion here.

Comment: I think my idea is similar to what chiastic-security provided.

Answer (score 0):

public static boolean pal(String s,int start,int end){

```
    if(end-start==1||end==start)
        return true;

    if(s.charAt(start)==s.charAt(end))
        return pal(s.substring(start+1, end),0,end-2);

    else{

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
        sb.deleteCharAt(start);
        String x=new String(sb);
        if(x.equals(sb.reverse().toString()))
            return true;

        StringBuilder sb2=new StringBuilder(s);
        sb2.deleteCharAt(end);
        String x2=new String(sb2);
        if(x2.equals(sb2.reverse().toString()))
            return true;


    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following,f and b are the indices at which characters do not match

```
int canwemakepal(char *str)//str input string
{
    long int f,b,len,i,j;
   int retval=0;
   len=strlen(str);
    f=0;b=len-1;
    while(str[f]==str[b] && f<b)//continue matching till we dont get a mismatch
    {
        f++;b--;
    }
    if(f>=b)//if the index variable cross over each other, str is palindrome,answer is yes
    {
        retval=1;//true
    }
    else if(str[f+1]==str[b])//we get a mismatch,so check if removing character at str[f] will give us a palindrome
    {
        i=f+2;j=b-1;
        while(str[i]==str[j] && i<j)
        {
            i++;j--;
        }
        if(i>=j)
        retval=1;
        else
        retval=0;
    }
    else if(str[f]==str[b-1])//else check the same for str[b]
    {
        i=f+1;j=b-2;
        while(str[i]==str[j] && i<j)
        {
            i++;j--;
        }
        if(i>=j)
        retval=1;
        else
        retval=0;
    }
    else 
    retval=0;

    return retval;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I created this solution,i tried with various input giving correct result,still not accepted as correct solution,Check it n let me know if m doing anything wrong!! Thanks in advance.
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = s.nextInt();
    String result[] = new String[t];
    short i = 0;
    while(i < t)
    {
        String str1 = s.next();
        int length  = str1.length();
        String str2 = reverseString(str1);
        if(str1.equals(str2))
        {
                result[i] = "Yes";
        }
        else 
        {
                if(length == 2)
                {
                    result[i] = "Yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    int x = 0,y = length-1;

                    int counter = 0;
                    while(x<y)
                    {
                        if(str1.charAt(x) == str1.charAt(y))
                        {
                            x++;
                            y--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            counter ++;
                            if(str1.charAt(x) == str1.charAt(y-1))
                            {
                                y--;
                            }
                            else if(str1.charAt(x+1) == str1.charAt(y))
                            {
                                x++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                counter ++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if(counter >= 2)
                    {
                        result[i] = "No";
                    }
                    else
                        result[i]="Yes";
                }

        }
        i++;

    } // Loop over

    for(int j=0; j<i;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(result[j]);
    }
}

public static String reverseString(String original)
{
    int length = original.length();
    String reverse = "";
     for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);
    return reverse;  
}
```